# How should http cache actually work?

Tags: http, http-headers, browser-cache

I know this is actually a old thing but I really got questions about this and how it was supposed to work when it started. So I got at least these four important cache headers I can send back to the client (`Last-Modified`, `Cache-Control`, `Expires` and `ETag`)

Example situation for question 2.2:

So let's say I got some site with articles.
There might be a new article every 15 minutes to 7 days.
So I set `Cache-Control` and `Expires` to cache for 15 min so the client always got the newest version of it.

What I think about `ETag` and `Last-Modified` at the moment:

I just put some hash of the content in there and I can send the client `304` if `If-None-Match` == `ETag`.

I can send the client `304` if `If-Modified-Since` >= `Last-Modified`.

Questions

1. Do I need `Cache-Control` **and** `Expires` to support all browsers or not ?
2. It looks like `Cache-Control` and `Expires` only tells my browser how long the content should be cached on the computer right?

   - So I can only use `ETag` and `Last-Modified` to find out when I should send `304` right?
   - So I could just set `Cache-Control` and `Expires` to forever and just send the client the new version if `ETag` or `Last-Modified` changed that?

     - Because this works in my browser but will this work in all browsers?
3. Do I need `ETag` **and** `Last-Modified` to support all browsers or not ?
4. `Pragma` looks like another cache header similar to `Cache-Control`, which browsers are using `Pragma` and do I need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Do I need `Cache-Control` and `Expires` to support all browsers or not ?*

`Cache-Control` is introduced in HTTP 1.1 and hence only supported on clients supporting HTTP 1.1. `Expires` is supported since HTTP 1.0. If both are specified, then `Cache-Control` takes precedence and `Expires` is ignored altogether.

---

> *It looks like `Cache-Control` and `Expires` only tells my browser how long the content should be cached on the computer right?*

Basically, yes. If the `Cache-Control` is absent (and thus `Expires` will be used) or set right with `max-age`.

---

> *So I can only use `ETag` and `Last-Modified` to find out when I should send 304 right?*

Here, your question starts to be confusing. You actually need to check `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` headers for that. Usually, browser sends only one of them on a conditional GET request and if it matches with the current value of `ETag` or `Last-Modified` in the server, then return 304 along with the `ETag` header. Note that if browser sends them both for some reason, then you can just ignore `If-Modified-Since`.

---

> *So I could just set `Cache-Control` and `Expires` to forever and just send the client the new version if `ETag` or `Last-Modified` changed that?*

No. If you set it to forever, the client will never send a (conditional) request until the enduser pressed (Ctrl)+F5. You need to set the `Cache-Control: max-age` or `Expires` to the desired cache time (to 15 minutes in the future maybe?).

---

> *Because this works in my browser but will this work in all browsers?*

Watch out how you test: pressing F5 will always send a conditional GET request. But a simple page-to-page navigation and form submits (like as in real world) won't send a conditional GET request! Pressing Ctrl+F5 will ignore the cache and send a brand new GET request.

---

> *Do I need ETag and Last-Modified to support all browsers or not ?*

All browsers support both. Browsers are required to send ETag back via `If-None-Match` if it has been received from the server and browser needs to perform a conditional GET request. The `Last-Modified` is for them optional and usually only sent if `ETag` is absent on the resource. See also [RFC 2616 section 13.3.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3.4).

---

> *Pragma looks like another cache header similar to Cache-Control, which browsers are using Pragma and do I need it?*

You don't need it if you want to cache. You only need it if you want to *not* cache (in order to cover HTTP 1.0 clients/proxies, whose population is currently steadily decreasing, though).

---

If you're familiar with Java, or can at least decipher it, then you may find this article helpful: [FileServiet supporting resume and caching and GZIP](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html).

#### See also:

- [Caching tutorial for webmasters](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)
- [Caching in HTTP (RFC2616 section 13)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html)

Comment: So the browser won't even send a HTTP request if `Cache-Control` says that the cached version can be used right? So a HTTP request will only be send if `Cache-Control` says that the cached version is outdated but if the server responds with 304 the browser will **still** use the cached version right? If both questions are right then will the respond get cached (local) when `max-age=0` or only if it is at least `max-age=1`? (So that there's sth. that can be used when the server responds with 304.)

Comment: That's correct. Note that the browser will keep sending conditional GET requests unless you send an updated `Cache-Control` or `Expires` header back along with the 304 which basically postpones the cache more.